# How do you use an HTTP/HTTPS proxy with boto3?

Tags: proxy, boto3

On the old `boto` library is was simple enough to use the `proxy`, `proxy_port`, `proxy_user` and `proxy_pass` parameters when you open a connection. However, I could not find any equivalent way of programmatically define the proxy parameters on boto3. :(

Comment: At the moment, I'm having to use something like:

`import os ;os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://yourproxy.com:1234";
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "https://yourproxy1.com:1234"`

Comment: I did not find any mention on the documentation that this would work. For example, on boto using `HTTPS_PROXY` would not work, only `HTTP_PROXY`.

Comment: Anyway, opened an issue at the boto3 GitHub repository: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/338

Comment: Seems like the devs thinks that setting the environment is a worthy replacement (I don't).

Comment: They've added this as a feature request now!

Comment: When using environment variables (related but different from this question) `HTTPS_PROXY` works for me but not `HTTP_PROXY`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As of at least version 1.5.79, botocore accepts a `proxies` argument in the botocore config.

e.g.

```
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(proxies={'https': 'foo.bar:3128'}))
```

**boto3 resource**
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.resource

**botocore config**
https://botocore.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/config.html#botocore.config.Config

Comment: I'm using boto3==1.4.6, botocore==1.6.6, but this does not seem to be working for me. Could you please provide a full example loading a file into a bucket, or something similar?

Comment: Since AWS uses HTTPS for all endpoints, try this configuration:
`boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(proxies={'https': 'foo.bar:3128'}))` (note that it's http**s**)

Comment: I had the same issue with STS. I've put that config into client and it worked, In case someone else need:
`conn = boto3.client('sts', config=Config(proxies={'http': 'myproxy', 'https': 'myproxy'}))`

Answer (score 19):

If you user proxy server does not have a password 
try the following:

```
import os
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://proxy.com:port"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "https://proxy.com:port"
```

if you user proxy server has a password
try the following:

```
import os
os.environ["HTTP_PROXY"] = "http://user:password@proxy.com:port"
os.environ["HTTPS_PROXY"] = "https://user:password@proxy.com:port"
```

Comment: Although ensure you correctly include quotations around your envirion values. This answer has them missing at the beginning of the proxy

Comment: This works, but changing an environment variable is troublesome. If along your program you need to perform an http request to other server, such request will get routed through the s3 proxy server, which is not what you want. You can kind of solve this by restoring both env variables to their original values after you are finished querying s3, but I wish there was a better solution.

Comment: @albarji, it depends on how you design your application, it is a basic principle to environment values isolate from the main application.  Then you may have s3_proxy.config, serverA_proxy.config

Answer (score 3):

Apart from altering the environment variable, I'll present what I found in the code.

Since boto3 uses botocore, I had a look through the source code:

https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/66008c874ebfa9ee7530d944d274480347ac3432/botocore/endpoint.py#L265

From this link, we end up at:

```
    def _get_proxies(self, url):
        # We could also support getting proxies from a config file,
        # but for now proxy support is taken from the environment.
        return get_environ_proxies(url)
```

...which is called by `proxies = self._get_proxies(final_endpoint_url)` in the `EndpointCreator` class.

Long story short, if you're using python2 it will use the `getproxies` method from urllib2 and if you're using python3, it will use urllib3.

`get_environ_proxies` is expecting a dict containing `{'http:' 'url'}` (and I'm guessing `https` too).

You could always `patch` the code, but that is poor practice.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the rare occasions when I would recommend monkey-patching, at least until the Boto developers allow connection-specific proxy settings:

```
import botocore.endpoint
def _get_proxies(self, url):
    return {'http': 'http://someproxy:1234/', 'https': 'https://someproxy:1234/'}
botocore.endpoint.EndpointCreator._get_proxies = _get_proxies
import boto3
```